# Swift: How to use sizeof?

Tags: swift

In order to integrate with C API's while using Swift, I need to use the sizeof function.  In C, this was easy.  In Swift, I am in a labyrinth of type errors.

I have this code:

```
var anInt: Int = 5
var anIntSize: Int = sizeof(anInt)
```

The second line has the error "'NSNumber' is not a subtype of 'T.Type'".  Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use sizeof as follows:

```
let size = sizeof(Int)
```

`sizeof` uses the type as the parameter.

If you want the size of the `anInt` variable you can pass the `dynamicType` field to `sizeof`.

Like so:

```
var anInt: Int = 5
var anIntSize: Int = sizeof(anInt.dynamicType)
```

Or more simply (pointed out by user102008):

```
var anInt: Int = 5
var anIntSize: Int = sizeofValue(anInt)
```

Comment: or `let anIntSize = sizeofValue(anInt)`

Answer (score 129):

**Updated for Swift 3**

Be careful that `MemoryLayout<T>.size` means something different than `sizeof` in C/Obj-C. You can read this old thread  https://devforums.apple.com/message/1086617#1086617

Swift uses an generic type to make it explicit that the number is known at compile time.

To summarize, `MemoryLayout<Type>.size` is the space required for a single instance while `MemoryLayout<Type>.stride` is the distance between successive elements in a contiguous array.  `MemoryLayout<Type>.stride` in Swift is the same as `sizeof(type)` in C/Obj-C.

To give a more concrete example:

```
struct Foo {
  let x: Int
  let y: Bool
}

MemoryLayout<Int>.size      // returns 8 on 64-bit
MemoryLayout<Bool>.size     // returns 1
MemoryLayout<Foo>.size      // returns 9
MemoryLayout<Foo>.stride    // returns 16 because of alignment requirements
MemoryLayout<Foo>.alignment // returns 8, addresses must be multiples of 8
```

Comment: Wow this is a pretty serious change from what sizeof used to do. Led to some bugs when our team transitioned to Swift 3.

Comment: i cant find MemoryLayout in swift 2.3

Answer (score 32):

Swift 3 now has `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue:)` which can look up the size dynamically.

Using a generic function that in turn uses `MemoryLayout<Type>` will have unexpected results if you e.g. pass it a reference of protocol type. This is because — as far as I know — the compiler then has all the type information it needs to fill in the values at compile time, which is not apparent when looking at the function call. You would then get the *size of the protocol*, not the current value.

Answer (score 20):

In Xcode 8 with Swift 3 beta 6 there is no function sizeof (). But if you want, you can define one for your needs. This new sizeof function works as expected with an array. This was not possible with the old builtin sizeof function.

```
let bb: UInt8 = 1
let dd: Double = 1.23456

func sizeof <T> (_ : T.Type) -> Int
{
    return (MemoryLayout<T>.size)
}

func sizeof <T> (_ : T) -> Int
{
    return (MemoryLayout<T>.size)
}

func sizeof <T> (_ value : [T]) -> Int
{
    return (MemoryLayout<T>.size * value.count)
}

sizeof(UInt8.self)   // 1
sizeof(Bool.self)    // 1
sizeof(Double.self)  // 8
sizeof(dd)           // 8
sizeof(bb)           // 1

var testArray: [Int32] = [1,2,3,4]
var arrayLength = sizeof(testArray)  // 16
```

You need all versions of the sizeof function, to get the size of a variable and to get the correct size of a data-type and of an array.

If you only define the second function, then sizeof(UInt8.self) and sizeof(Bool.self) will result in "8". If you only define the first two functions, then sizeof(testArray) will result in "8".

Comment: As I get it, your sizeof function returns the size of an object, in bytes. Right? So, why does it return "24", when I give the following string as a parameter? "11111111111"

Comment: This is because of the way, dynamically strings are decoded in Swift Unicode

Comment: While this will work for built in types, I think the sizeof array method has limited value.  See the size versus stride discussion above.  An array of arbitrary structs often has special alignment requirements which will make the actually number of contiguous bytes saved greater.

Comment: I don't recommend this. It gives the caller the illusion of looking up the type dynamically while in fact doing it statically. If you pass in a reference of protocol type you will get the size of the protocol, not the current value.

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 4**

From Xcode 9 onwards there is now a property called `.bitWidth`, this provides another way of writing `sizeof:` functions for instances and integer types:

```
func sizeof<T:FixedWidthInteger>(_ int:T) -> Int {
    return int.bitWidth/UInt8.bitWidth
}

func sizeof<T:FixedWidthInteger>(_ intType:T.Type) -> Int {
    return intType.bitWidth/UInt8.bitWidth
}

sizeof(UInt16.self) // 2
sizeof(20) // 8
```

But it would make more sense for consistency to replace `sizeof:` with `.byteWidth`:

```
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    var byteWidth:Int {
        return self.bitWidth/UInt8.bitWidth
    }
    static var byteWidth:Int {
        return Self.bitWidth/UInt8.bitWidth
    }
}

1.byteWidth // 8
UInt32.byteWidth // 4
```

It is easy to see why `sizeof:` is thought ambiguous but I'm not sure that burying it in MemoryLayout was the right thing to do. See the reasoning behind the shifting of `sizeof:` to `MemoryLayout` [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/9cf2685293108ea3efcbebb7ee6a8618b83d4a90/proposals/0101-standardizing-sizeof-naming.md).

Comment: This makes things much simpler and easier to understand. Thanks Apple! (Sarcasm).....

Comment: How do you do this with Float?

Comment: You use `.bitWidth` and `.byteWidth`.  Is your mentioning `.byteWidth` an error?

Comment: @AlexZavatone no, it is within the extension written after the colon.