# NSProcessInfo().systemUptime is wrong

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uptime

I have a trouble with getting `NSTimeInterval` after system reboot. This functions gave me a wrong result. The reboot time is restarting when device's battery is charged. There is a trouble on iPhone 5s and iPad 3 (the new). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this method and it helps me

```
 public static func uptime() -> (days: Int, hrs: Int, mins: Int, secs: Int) {
            var currentTime = time_t()
            var bootTime    = timeval()
            var mib         = [CTL_KERN, KERN_BOOTTIME]

            // NOTE: Use strideof(), NOT sizeof() to account for data structure
            // alignment (padding)
            // http://stackoverflow.com/a/27640066
            // https://devforums.apple.com/message/1086617#1086617
            var size = strideof(timeval)

            let result = sysctl(&mib, u_int(mib.count), &bootTime, &size, nil, 0)

            if result != 0 {
                #if DEBUG
                    print("ERROR - \(__FILE__):\(__FUNCTION__) - errno = "
                        + "\(result)")
                #endif

                return (0, 0, 0, 0)
            }
```