# Use of unresolved identifier 'sizeof'

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nsdata

I'm trying to send a position between two devices, so I need to convert the position to NSData. I found something on the net but I have an error: Use of unresolved identifier 'sizeof'. I don't know how to solve, could you help me?. Here's my code:

```
var error: Error?
    var positionToSend = car.position
    let dataSend = NSData(bytes: &positionToSend, length: sizeof(CGPoint))
    try? match.sendData(toAllPlayers: dataSend, with: .unreliable)
    if error != nil {
    }
```

Comment: For sizeof see [Swift: How to use sizeof?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27640066/1187415). – Using the approach from [round trip Swift number types to/from Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023838/1187415) it would be `let dataSend = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &positionToSend, count: 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite your code in Swift 4 as:

```
var positionToSend = car.position
let dataSend = Data(bytes: &positionToSend, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: positionToSend))
do {
    try match.sendData(toAllPlayers: dataSend, with: .unreliable)
} catch {
    //Write code for `if error != nil`...
    print(error)
}
```

You do not need `withUnsafePointer`.

Comment: Excuse me, and If I want to receive this data sent?

Comment: @AndreaCulot, it depends on many things. Have you got the received data as `Data`? Or something else?

Comment: Seems you have started a new thread now. There are many readers who can help you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the `error` variable is pointless. `try?` doesn't affect `error` at all.

`sizeof` has been changed to `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue:`. The argument is `positionToSend`, not the type `CGPoint`

The Swift 3+ way to create `Data` (not `NSData`) from a `CGPoint` is

```
let dataSend = Data(bytes: &positionToSend, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: positionToSend))
```

Comment: You don't need the `UnsafePointer()`